# Por que usar um empacotador como o WebPack?

Tags: aplicação-web, webpack

Estava conversando com um amigo sobre o flash e como todo o código é compilado em um único arquivo e "zuamos" sobre os "1tera" que o usuário tem que baixar, claro, exagerando...

Mas então surgiu uma dúvida:
**Qual a vantagem de usar o WebPack, por exemplo, para empacotar o código?**

Trabalhamos um pouco com Angular 5/6 e todo o código (inclusive o HTML e CSS) é empacotado em 3 arquivos, o que talvez possa causar algum incomodo para usuários com uma internet mais lenta, em contrapartida ao carregamento "aos poucos" de uma aplicação web tradicional com *imports* de JS e CSS.

Se os melhores *frameworks* *frontend* usam, deve valer a pena, mas qual o ganho em questão de performance ao empacotar o código?

Comment: Talvez a pergunta possua uma resposta canônica, mas preciso comentar/solicitar algumas coisas. Se existe uma preocupação grande sobre o desempenho da aplicação para usuários com internet lenta, talvez seja o caso de rever a utilização do Angular. Frameworks em geral resolvem alguns problemas específicos adicionando uma carga geralmente desnecessária ao projeto. Outra coisa é que você parte da premissa que deve valer a pena porque os "melhores frameworks" utilizam; qual é o seu critério para eleger os "melhores frameworks"? Quais seriam esses?

Comment: Com melhores quis dizer os mais famosos, talvez não sejam os melhores ou sejam melhores em um determinado assunto mas foi isto que quis dizer, como angular, vue e react, por exemplo.

Comment: Quando você fala em "usuários com uma internet mais lenta" irão ser negativamente afetado por uma única requisição a um "super bundle" está indo de contramão ao que o próprio webpack prega. Se sua aplicação é demasiada complexa, a mesma ira realizar obviamente inúmeras requisições HTTP, e isso sim pode causar um problema pra quem não usufrui de uma conexão de qualidade, você pode entender isso no próprio site deles aqui https://webpack.js.org/concepts/why-webpack/.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente vou te dizer que a minha visão do WebPack e outros empacotadores é um pouco diferente da sua visão. E que podem ter outros usuários que vão discordar desse ponte de vista que vou te dar.

Talvez o principal beneficiado do WebPack é o Desenvolvedor. Na verdade no meu ponto de vista o usuário final do WebPack é o próprio deve e não o usuário que vai acessar o site. Te explico porque.

Acredito que a principal vantagem dos empacotadores é fazer uma parte do trabalho dos desenvolvedores e automatizar várias rotinas... Me justifico com esses exemplos. O WebPack vai *prefixar* todos seus estilos de CSS para vc não ter problema de `crossbrowser`. Ele vai compilar seus `SASS`, `SCSS`, `LESS` ou `Stylus` em uma folha de estilo padrão `.CSS` que o browser vai conseguir ler. Ele vai fazer os includes de tudo que vc quiser no documento, ele vai usar algo como o `Babel` por exemplo para tratar a compatibilidade do seu `Java Script` para browsers antigos. Ele vai *minificar* seu código, remover comentários etc...

Então vejo que o usuário final é o Dev. e não o usuário que vai acessar a plataforma. Mas logicamente vejo vantagens pro usuário do sistema tb, pois vc vai entregar para ele uma código otimizado, mas que poderia ter sido otimizado na mão, não necessariamente com um Webpack da vida.

Até pq, na verdade boa parte do que o WebPack são boas práticas que todos deveriam fazer, pois são elas que vão impactar diretamente o usuário do sistema como *minificar* o código e *prefixar* as propriedades do css, ou converter imagens em `Base64` ou gerar `sprites`, isso sim vai trazer uma melhor experiencia para o usuário e uma melhor performance na entrega, mas isso tudo são boas práticas e que com o WebPack fica mais fácil para fazer.